# Add vague Objective option to CSO's "What type of work are you seeking?"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Some of us checking this out are not necessarily looking for permanent or contract work, just...sniffing crotches, so to speak.  (Or more accurately in this context, lifting our tail to let others sniff.)  We are happily employed but open to ideas.  The current options are too rigid:

- Full time permanent
- Temporary contract
- Telecommuting (working remotely)

So, additional options would be nice.  This could/would be a way to describe folks who are looking for start-up opportunities, etc.  Maybe something like

- Open to ideas

Also for students:

- Internship or Co-op for (check all that apply)

  - summer
  - fall
  - winter
  - spring

Comment: How about "It's complicated".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I basically agree that a "Open to ideas" option would be nice.

But, looking at [the FAQ](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq), and especially this part:

> When hiring managers search through
>   CVs, they want to know that they’re
>   looking at active, serious job
>   applicants. If it were free to post a
>   CV, **a lot of applicants that weren’t
>   looking for jobs**, or who knew that
>   they had no reasonable chance of
>   getting a job, **would post them**, making
>   it harder for the employers to find
>   serious applicants.

...I'm not sure it fits what the SO team had in mind. They'll obviously want to market the site as one that's full of "serious applicants".

Then again, why not - it should be easy enough (to add functionality) for employers to filter out these "Open to ideas" people if they only happen to be looking for developers who *really* are looking for a job right now.

Comment: I would like this option.

Comment: Yes, exactly!  Having a *"Open to other options"* check box would actually *help* employers distinguish between read-to-go and just-sniffing" folks.  It works for one and all.

Answer (score 3):

What about a 5th option - for student accounts - internships.

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea to me.

Answer (score 2):

This might be hard since it opens up the possibility of applicants who are not as "serious" as others.  I imagine that one of the selling points of the site to employers is that the individuals are actually looking for work as opposed to simply floating resumes in the hopes of snagging a better deal.  On the other hand, it provides a way for people who **are** simply floating resumes to be honest about it.  This will happen -- even $99/yr is a small investment -- so I'm generally in favor of it.  Perhaps an "other" option with a field for an explanation would be sufficient to cover the many scenarios that fall outside the current choices.