# Please add an option for not actively looking to the career site

Tags: feature-request, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add vague Objective option to CSO’s “What type of work are you seeking?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24987/add-vague-objective-option-to-csos-what-type-of-work-are-you-seeking)

Maybe there should be an option under "What type of work are you seeking?" that would mean something like "I am not actively looking but if something comes up I may be interested".

Alternatively this could be split out so in addition to perm, contract etc. you would say how actively you are looking.

Any opinions?

Comment: Probable duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24987/add-vague-objective-option-to-csos-what-type-of-work-are-you-seeking

Comment: It took me a little longer to parse the title of that question... but yeah, this is a duplicate alright.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly the type of thing they *don't* want "filed" in the database.