# Do moderators still have binding close votes for duplicate questions?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, moderators, binding-vote

We just got a [new UI for duplicate close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes). When someone flags it as a duplicate, it asks the user to see the if question that it might be a dupe of answers their question. They have the option to close the question or to edit it.

I know that the diamond moderators close votes are binding, but I was wondering if that is still the case now that there is the new duplicate close vote box.

Comment: Why wouldn't that be the case? All moderator votes are binding.

Comment: @Doorknob It seems like the person who asked the question is getting more say in if it is a dupe, so I wasn't sure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moderators' votes and other users' votes aren't changed in any way.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if this was still the case because the OP, it seems, is getting more say in deciding if the question is a dupe or not.

Comment: @michaelpri In a way, yes, that's what's happening. We see many cases where a duplicate suggestion either has the asker go "oops, yeah, that's it" and then the question never gets closed due to low views *or* an argument breaks out in comments over whether or not it's a duplicate after all. This change is intended to address that by allowing the asker to agree with the vote and insta-close *or* to more clearly guide them towards a constructive way of disagreeing - by editing their question to highlight its differences.