# Show the OP's name instead of Community when they votes to close

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, community-user

Currently, when the original poster of the question votes to close a question, the close vote is attributed to the Community user, which can lead to confusion on who actually voted to close the question.

[image: UI showing Community ♦ moderator voting to close a question]

Yes, it does say that the question author authorized a pending duplicate vote and whatnot, but that isn't indicated anywhere except for in a hidden thing that most won't look to see.

Like nicael [says here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250960/238126), there really isn't a point to hiding that the question author approved a duplicate vote. Even if they didn't at the most specific level vote to close, it's makes for a better user experience to have something more like this:

[image: Dupehammer vote attributed to the OP]

Answer (score 5):

> when the original poster of the question votes to close a question, the close vote is attributed to the Community user

This is incorrect. If you vote to close this question, you'll see it's a normal vote to close. Nothing changed in the voting-to-close mechanism.

The action of approving a pending duplicate vote is distinct from casting a vote of your own. A user may choose to do one but not the other, or to do both. The interface should not report two different actions as being the same.

---

Screenshot for reference:

[image: screenshot]