# Why are "approving a pending duplicate vote" and "casting a close-as-duplicate vote" different actions when done by the asker?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, original-poster

When a question is flagged/close-voted as duplicate by other users, the question asker has the possibility to [unilaterally approve this vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10363/643262) and have the question closed. If this happens, the last close-vote is [attributed to the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/643262), instead of the asker.

This has [occasionally led to confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342152/643262), and there is an old [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254616/643262), to list the asker as the last close-voter. I agree with that feature request, because it would definitely give more accurate information.

The only answer to the feature request says that "unilaterally approving a duplicate vote" and "casting a close vote" are different actions. This is true, as the asker has the option to just cast a non-binding close vote.

My question is, **why do we have these two different actions?** If the asker agrees with the proposed duplicate, why would they want to cast a non-binding vote instead of a binding vote?

Comment: Well I do understand why the community user casts the last binding vote, as it has mod rights to do so. Wouldn't it look increadibly strange to see a question closed by a single user that is not a moderator nor a gold badge holder.

Comment: @Luuklag that is true, but it might look less strange if the name of the user is marked as OP with the standard bluish shadowing. People would then see that a question was closed by its asker, which looks less strange. In any case, I am more curious about why the two options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about privileges and reputation.

Any user, even with 1 reputation and without a single privilege, can click the "I agree, close the question" button and have it closed instantly as a duplicate.

The ability to cast (non binding) close votes on your own questions comes as part of the "View close votes" privilege, usually given at 250 reputation. That's a lot more than 1 rep.

Worth to mention that similar thing happens with flagging vs. casting close votes: at 15 rep one can flag a question as off topic, and at 3k rep, a user can cast actual close vote, but can also still flag. In such a case, **the flag is turned automatically into a close vote**, so logically, it can be applied to this case: if a user with 250 rep try to cast a non binding close vote as a duplicate on their own question, and there's a pending close vote/flag already, make it as if the OP clicked the "It solved my problem" button.