# Why don't I get credit for closing one of my own questions as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just agreed with a duplicate suggestion for one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767457/why-are-my-mfc-dialogs-showing-different-styles-in-visual-studio-and-at-runtime).  It's now showing that it was closed as a duplicate by the person who raised the duplicate suggestion and Community.  Since it was my yes this solves my problem click that triggered the closing/status change shouldn't I get credit instead?

Comment: Technical reason: since it's not actual close vote, and can be done with 1 rep, it's attributed to the Community account

Comment: If you mouse over "Community" in the list of close voters, you should get a blurb of text that says something to the effect that the Asker agreed with a Duplicate close reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community user will always appear in the list if you've used the [self-closing feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes).

You appear in the list only when you vote to close using the *close* link (note that flagging for closure isn't counted as a close vote). So, to get the credit (though this doesn't really matter?), you should've voted before clicking "this solved my problem".

Comment: OK, I don't like it; but I see it's been thoroughly argued at the time of implementation.

Comment: @Dan Neither do I, as expressed by [answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250960) that question (point one).