# How many community flags are needed for closing a question?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close

I've started to wonder seeing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271322/spoiler-syntax-doesnt-work-on-tags) (I've seen a number of similarly closed with the Community♦ appearing at Stack Overflow as well).

I know that the OP can accept duplicates and this will appear as Community♦, but I've seen such for other close reasons as well (I believe so at least, can be wrong I have no actual samples I could show now).

How many flags from users below 3k does it need to close a question (probably along the +3k users close votes)?

How many flags are needed to just let the Community♦ close a question (without any close votes from +3k users)?

Is this already well documented somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flags themselves don't close the question, the answer is "infinity". The more flags there're, the more priority the question gets in the Close Votes review queue, but they don't contribute to the resulting closure banner anyhow.

In the case you've just seen, OP clicked "that solved my problem" button in the appearing dupe banner, which caused the Community to close the question. More info on this: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I well know, that OP can accept a dupe, but I was asking for the more general case (seen this for other close reasons as well).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The Community user does not close questions for any reason other than duplicates as mentioned above.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I appear to have answered the other reasons in the first paragraph?... As for you edit: could you please come with examples?

Comment: @nicael Sorry, I don't have any examples. Just from my memorization, but I could be just wrong with that.

Comment: @animuson Would you mind documenting this behavior of the SE engine with an answer here. I already have mentioned, that my memorization could be just wrong (beginning Alzheimer's probably ;-)).