# What is the exact required timing to get the “Speedy Delivery” hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

The short description for the `Speedy Delivery` hat reads

> answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked, scoring 3 and getting accepted

I am not sure as to how the timing works here.

Do I only have to post an answer within 30 minutes of the questions creation and some time after that the answer has to get accepted and hit the score 3 mark.

Or does **all** of that have to happen in the 30 minutes after the creation of the question?

In particular do the upvotes and acceptance have to happen at most 30 minutes after question creation or after answer creation?

Comment: I strongly believe all 3 should be within 30 minutes from the moment of question being asked

Comment: @Sha only posting should happen within 30 mins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should answer within 30 minutes, but it's not required for all the three votes and accept to be in the first 30 minutes (e.g. you answered a question in 27 minutes, get 3 votes and accept a day later, and after third vote you get the hat).

Claim: I provided [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271329) and got the **accept 3 hours later** and the **third vote 5 hours later**, and the hat quickly following next. Why am I so sure I got the hat for that post? Because by the time I got three votes, it was my only post during Winterbash scoring 3 (previous was posted Nov 25, way before the Winterbash started).

Comment: Any proof for that statement? (either a dev saying this, or actual hat being earned this way.)

Comment: @Sha I got this hat with the votes coming a day later :)

Comment: Okay, when has the acceptance have to occur? Within the 30 minutes or some time after? And are there any sources for your "claim"?

Comment: And you are sure you got the head for the exact question you got the final third upvote for?

Comment: @luk Yes, because on Meta it was my first answer scoring 3 after the winterbash began. The previous was posted by me Nov 25.

Comment: Okay, when did your answer get accepted? From the sounds of it my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34381614/2442804) could still earn me the hat, correct?

Comment: @luk let's check if it can :)

Comment: haha, dirty tricks at work here XD lets see, dont know what kind of delay the hats have.

Comment: Few minutes, I'd say 10 minutes at most.

Comment: @luk looks like you've got the hat :)

Comment: Positive, still however not sure about when the acceptance has to appear - do you know when your answer got accepted?

Comment: @luk I've already edited: 3 hours after I posted the answer.

Comment: Ah, okay, perfect then - I would have actually expected that everything has to happen within 30 minutes, but am actually glad that is not the case ;)

Comment: This description is accurate.

Comment: thanks @Pops for stopping by and making it official!