# Answer marked as accepted...nice getting more answers but is there any way to stop all this?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I asked for some assistance on the "The Workplace" Stack Exchange site recently. I got a great number of answers and ultimately accepted one of them. I understand we always want to have answers later on, because you never know they could actually be better than the accepted answer.

But...after a while it gets old. The number of notifications I get, comments, additional answers, etc. is overwhelming. I use the mobile app and continue to get more notifications and the fact that it became a hot network question didn't help.  Is there a way I, as the OP, can mark one of my questions as "closed" right away and provide a comment such as "OP is requesting no additional answers or comments".

Basically I am happy with the answer - if it were Stack Overflow I can understand technology changes. But the workplace is pretty straightforward, and the answer holds true (in most cases).

How can I close this question - should I just flag a moderator and state I no longer want comments / answers?

Comment: Note that it's unlikely that a CM will disassociate your account from a question just because you don't want notifications from it.

Comment: @Catija You have a legal right to request disassociation from content as per the CC license.  They don't have the right to refuse the request.  I also don't see why a mod would have a problem with disassociation in a case like this anyway, not that it's relevant.

Comment: @Servy That's ... not really what I said. Disassociations are extreme and come with many other side effects... like loss of the reputation earned and all connection to the post. Also, **mods** do not have any control over this, only CMs. Disassociation should be a last choice, not the first option.

Comment: @Catija Yes, there are side effects to doing them.  And you're free to consider them a last resort as much as you want, but SE is *obligated* to disassociate posts upon request from the author.  They don't have the right to refuse the request, regardless of what the side effects are and how much they do or don't want to fulfill them.

Comment: if you could find a duplicate you would be able to [singlehandedly dupe-close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250974/165773) your own question, this would prevent adding new answers

Answer (score 9):

That question isn't there to just give you, and only you, an answer.  It's there to create a useful solution to *anyone* with that problem.  To ensure that it provides the best solution possible, it's important that answers and comments continue to be allowed to be posted over time (so long as they're inherently appropriate contributions).  Just because you aren't personally interested in the question anymore doesn't give you the right to prevent other people from working to improve it for all of the people who *are* (or will be) interested in it.

The most you could do is request that the post be disassociated from your account so that you are no longer notified of any activity on the post, as that still leaves the post for the rest of the community to benefit from.

Comment: I agree however, it should be easier to simply mark it such that it no longer informs me about it.  I think this is something that should be out of the box.

Comment: @JonH But that's not what your question is asking for. Your question is asking for a way to shut down the discussion entirely, which isn't your call. If you want to request a way to silence notifications for a specific post, ask for that, but don't ask for a way to stop people from using the site just because you're happy with your answer.

Comment: @Catija - I have edited my question - thank you.

Comment: @JonH It's not appropriate to edit your question into a completely different question.  If you have a new question, ask a new question.